# App doesnt run without Fiddler certificate

Tags: https, certificate, fiddler

This seems to be a very old issue however, all the said solutions are not working for me. I am making a request to a client and receive a HTTPS reponse that I used fiddler to capture early on, however now my application doesn't work without Fiddler certificates. When I select the descrypt HTTPS traffic in fiddler then the app works or else it doesn't even if I remove the HTTPS capture option from Fiddler and remove the fiddler certificate.

I have also tried to remove fiddler altogether but that din't solve the issue as well. I am out of options as of now. This is my code

```
    Dim cert As X509Certificate = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("Cert Location")
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf OnCertificateValidation)
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(HttpWebRequest.Create(WebURL), HttpWebRequest)
    request.Method = "POST"
    Dim requestDataByte() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(CreateRequestXML)
    request.ContentLength = requestDataByte.Length
    Dim requestdata As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    requestdata.Write(requestDataByte, 0, requestDataByte.Length)
    requestdata.Close()
    request.GetRequestStream.Close()
    request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert)
    request.KeepAlive = False

    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
    If response.StatusCode > 400 Then
        MsgBox("Error:" + response.StatusDescription + vbCrLf + response.StatusCode)
    End If
    Dim response_stream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream
    response_stream.Close()
    response.Close()
    Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response_stream)
    _response = reader.ReadToEnd
    reader.Close()
```

I keep receiving the 500 internal server error. 
Edit: I was not closing the response connection properly before however I modified that part of the code long back. Shouldn't that modification have solved my problem?

I have modified the code as per the posts I could find online. But still unable to resolve the issue.

Comment: I am now closing the stream as well. However, no improvement. I also tried executing the program in another system, still the same issue. I would really like some help to solve this issue.

Comment: Consider moving the call to `ClientCertificates.Add` to just after the `Dim request` line. You should definitely remove the call `request.GetRequestStream.Close()` as you've already closed that stream when you called `requestData.Close()`

Comment: I forgot to update my question yesterday. In fact, I did exactly what you are suggesting and everything works now. I dint notice my WebRequest was incorrect because Fiddler was fixing it. I tried web exceptions to try and see what the issue was but just couldn't find out. Wish there was a way to figure this from some kind of debug information. I have made changes to my .Close() calls as well just as you suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the above problem is to have the ClientCertificates.add() method just after you define the request object. And to close your response streams properly by calling the appropriate .Close() methods.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that *Fiddler's* certificate has anything to do with this. The more likely explanation is that there's a problem in the way that your code is providing a *client certificate* to the server; that problem is remedied when Fiddler is in the middle (because Fiddler cannot take the client certificate sent by your application and pass it to the server).

So, stepping back, when you're running Fiddler, do you have a `%AppData%\Documents\Fiddler\ClientCertificate.cer` file on your disk? If so, Fiddler is sending that client certificate to the server. If not, then your server isn't getting a client certificate at all.